# First occurence in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that is sorted by Date

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":['2023-02-11','2023-02-10','2023-02-09','2023-02-08','2023-02-07','2023-02-06','2023-02-05'],
                   "A":['a','a','c','a','c','b','b'],
                   "B":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

```
Date        A   B
2023-02-11  a   1
2023-02-10  a   2
2023-02-09  c   3
2023-02-08  a   4
2023-02-07  c   5
2023-02-06  b   6
2023-02-05  b   7
```

And I want to create a new column `FirstTime` which is equal to 1 if that is the first time the symbol turns up in `A` and 0 otherwise. So the desired outcome looks like

```
Date        A   B   FirstTIme
2023-02-11  a   1   0
2023-02-10  a   2   0
2023-02-09  c   3   0
2023-02-08  a   4   1
2023-02-07  c   5   1
2023-02-06  b   6   0
2023-02-05  b   7   1
```

I know the idxmax and searchsorted method but not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data is sorted decreasingly by `Date`, you can just use `duplicated`. If data is not sorted, then sort it as such.

```
df['FirstTime'] = 1 - df['A'].duplicated(keep='last').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
         Date  A  B  FirstTime
0  2023-02-11  a  1          0
1  2023-02-10  a  2          0
2  2023-02-09  c  3          0
3  2023-02-08  a  4          1
4  2023-02-07  c  5          1
5  2023-02-06  b  6          0
6  2023-02-05  b  7          1
```

Comment: Whoo same time same logic up to the -1, almost scary :p (btw, explicit conversion to int is not necessary)

Answer (score 2):

Use `duplicated` on the date-sorted data:

```
df['FirstTime'] = df.sort_values(by='Date')['A'].duplicated().rsub(1)
```

If the data is already sorted by decreasing date:

```
df['FirstTime'] = df['A'].duplicated(keep='last').rsub(1)
```

Output:

```
         Date  A  B  FirstTime
0  2023-02-11  a  1          0
1  2023-02-10  a  2          0
2  2023-02-09  c  3          0
3  2023-02-08  a  4          1
4  2023-02-07  c  5          1
5  2023-02-06  b  6          0
6  2023-02-05  b  7          1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `drop_duplicates with keep = last` as follows?

```
df['FirstTime'] = 0
df.loc[df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['A'], keep = 'last').index, 'FirstTime'] = 1
```